# Open/Read File in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I can't read the file that's in the same folder in VS Code using

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fp:
```

and it returns
***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.txt'***
but I tried the same thing in Pycharm and it works as expected.

Does anyone know why?
Thanks!

Comment: how you run the file? do you open the terminal in the same directory where the file is located?

Comment: What does `os.path.abspath('filename.txt')` tell you?

Comment: @JonSG it just gives me the path of the filename.

Comment: Is that different than what you expect?

Comment: @JonSG it's the same as what I expect, that's the weird part